# Pushforward of a constant sheaf in the etale topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

This is a very basic question in etale cohomology.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z} /(n)$ on $\mathbb{A}^1$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ with $n$ coprime to the characteristic. Let $i: \mathbb{A}^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ be the inclusion. What is $i_{\ast}\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: This is $\mathbb{Z}/n$. This follow easily from the distinguished triangle $\mathcal{F}_\infty(-1)[-2]\rightarrow\mathcal{F}\rightarrow i_*\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}_\infty(-1)[-1]$ where $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ is the skyscraper sheaf $\mathbb{Z}/n$ on the point at infinity.

Comment: @user113969 Isn't that a bit of overkill? The pushfoward is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ since $\mathbb{A}^1$ is open-dense in $\mathbb{P}^1$. No?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes probably, I guess I work too much in derived categories and have to notice that $Ri_*\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hello. I do not understand your answers. Even in the Zariski topology the pushforward of a constant sheaf under an open dense immersion need not be constant, because the inverse image of an open connected set need not be connected. Consider for example the union of two lines meeting at a point, and the open subset obtained by removing the point where they meet.

Comment: What needs to be proved is that given an etale morphism to P1 from a connected scheme the pullback over A1 is still connected. It's true for curves because the map is quasi finite and removing finitely many points from a curve leaves it connected.

Anyway, I am also interested in the relative case where $k$ is replaced by an arbitrary variety - I'll be happy for help with that...